# Log4jdbc doesn't work in web project

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, struts2, log4j

Today, I integrate `Log4jdbc 1.2` with `Spring 3.1` `Struts 2.1` `Hibernate 4.1` in order to see the real SQL in console.

> My project run normally,however, I don't get the real SQL.The amazing
>   thing is that I do get the SQL when I test with JUnit.

here is my `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.debug=true

log4j.logger.jdbc.audit=INFO,jdbc
log4j.additivity.jdbc.audit=true

log4j.logger.jdbc.resultset=INFO,jdbc
log4j.additivity.jdbc.resultset=true

log4j.logger.jdbc.sqlonly=DEBUG,sql
log4j.additivity.jdbc.sqlonly=true

log4j.logger.jdbc.sqltiming=DEBUG,sqltiming
log4j.additivity.jdbc.sqltiming=true

log4j.logger.jdbc.connection=FATAL,connection
log4j.additivity.jdbc.connection=true

log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sql.File=./logs/sql.log
log4j.appender.sql.Append=false
log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sql.layout.ConversionPattern=-----> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n%n

log4j.appender.sqltiming=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sqltiming.File=./logs/sqltiming.log
log4j.appender.sqltiming.Append=false
log4j.appender.sqltiming.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sqltiming.layout.ConversionPattern=-----> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n%n

log4j.appender.jdbc=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.jdbc.File=./logs/jdbc.log
log4j.appender.jdbc.Append=false
log4j.appender.jdbc.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jdbc.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n

log4j.appender.connection=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.connection.File=./logs/connection.log
log4j.appender.connection.Append=false
log4j.appender.connection.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.connection.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n
```

And my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Spring14HibernateStruts2</display-name>
  <context-param>   
       <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>   
       <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>   
  </context-param> 

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>  
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>  
  </listener> 
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why do you need log4jdbc? Hibernate can also issue the sql (although without the actual parameters, replaced). However check if the proper Log4j is loaded and that you don't have log4j somewhere else in your classpath...

Comment: I know hibernate can show sql, but it is not the real sql.Actually, sometimes I want to run sql in my database directly to test it.And log4jdbc can show me sql with actual parameters.

Comment: Hibernate shows the actual sql but without parameters (which can be logged seperatly). But as mentioned I suspect you have multiple log4j instances in your application, make sure that there is no log4j in your application server.

Comment: You do remind me this, so I delete all things about log4j include `log4j.properties` and `context-param>` `<listener>` in `web.xml` and also the jar files, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I never mentioned you should remove the configuration etc. I suggested you check your app server for another log4j instance. If there is a log4j instance in your app server it isn't going to work (due to classloading).